# Uploading a file from a web app with dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am building a web app. I have to let a user upload a picture or drag-and-drop one into the browser. To help with this, I'm using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). My challenge is, I need to customize the appearance a bit.

My customization requires features that seem pretty forward in dropzone.js. Basically, I need: only one file can be uploaded at once. While the file is being uploaded, I need to show a progress bar. Once uploaded, I need to let the user either a) remove the existing picture or b) replace the picture with another one. In an attempt to this, I currently have the following HTML:

```
<div id="myDropZone" style="cursor:pointer;">
  <div class="files" id="previews">
    <div id="template" class="file-row">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li>
          <span class="preview" style="width:300px;"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
          <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
        </li>
        <li style="vertical-align:top;">
          <ul id="pictureActions" class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <button class="btn btn-default dz-clickable file-input-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                <span>Pick...</span>
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger btn-block" style="margin-top:8px;">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-left"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="uploadProgress" class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress>
          <span>Please wait...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="uploadPrompt">Drag-and-drop a picture here</div>
</div>
```

I am initializing this code as a dropzone using the following JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
    previewNode.id = "";
    var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
    previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

    var pictureDropZone = new Dropzone("div#myDropZone", {
        url: "/pictures/upload",
        clickable: true,
        uploadMultiple: false,
        autoProcessQueue: true,
        previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
        previewsContainer: "#previews",
        init: function () {
            this.on("complete", function (data) {
                $('#pictureActions').show();
                $('#uploadProgress').hide();
                $('#uploadPrompt').hide();
            });
        },
        uploadprogress: function (e, progress) {
          $('#uploadProgress').css('width', progress);
        },
        removedfile: function () {
            $('#previews').hide();
            $('#uploadPrompt').show();
        }
    });
});
```

There are several problems though. If I click the text `Drag-and-drop a picture here`, the file picker does not open. If I click outside of the text, the file picker opens. Also, this code works for the initial process of choosing a file. However, if I click the "Pick..." button, the page does a post back. In reality, I was expecting the file picker to appear again. If I click the "Delete" button, and then choose a file again from the file picker, the picture, upload progress and action buttons never appear.

I feel like I'm screwing up the initialization of the dropzone somehow. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I choose another picture or delete a picture and choose another one or open the file picker if I click the prompt text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code

```
this.on("complete", function (data) {
       $("#previews").show();      //This line added ... and it's worked... 
       $('#pictureActions').show();
       $('#uploadProgress').hide();
       $('#uploadPrompt').hide();
});
```

i think then line:  `$('#previews').hide();` you have hidden preview element, and this not change status when you append new image. :).

And this word but, You can see old picture you added, I think it's a new bug... I trying solute it... Have you idea for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/qek0xw1x/15/

Comment: Thank you for trying. However, there are still two problems: 1) The jsfiddle is not working in Chrome or Firefox. 2) If I remove a picture after adding it, then, add another picture, the first picture is still appears in the previews.

Comment: So. If #previews doesn't show again, you can't see delete button, and can't see **"Drag-and-drop a picture here"** again

Comment: **And this word but, You can see old picture you added, I think it's a new bug... I trying solute it... Have you idea for it.**
I have note it in answer, this a new bug.